# Finding a special type of spanning subgraph in a multigraph with all vertex-degrees a multiple of a constant

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a multigraph (without loops) and let $m>1$ be an integer. Suppose each vertex $x\in V$  has a degree $md(x)$ where $d(x)$ depends on the vertex (let's assume $d(x)>0$ for all vertexes so that the graph does not have isolated vertexes).

**Edit** (after Med's answer): Also suppose $\sum_{x\in V} d(x)=$even.

> Is it possible to find a spanning subgraph $G_1\subset G$ such that the degree of $x$ in $G_1$ is $(m-1)d(x)$ for all $x\in V$?

My gut tells me this is too good to be true but I can construct an example.

If a graph has such property, what can be said about the graph? Furthermore what can be said about $G$ if there is a nested sequence of graphs in $G$, i.e. $G\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset \cdots\supset G_{m-1}$ such that $G_{i+1}\subset G_i$ satisfies the above property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always true. Consider this particular example. A graph of three vertices, with the following adjacency matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix} 
  0  & 3  & 3\\ 
  3 & 0 & 1\\
  3 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

The degrees are

$d(v_1)=6,d(v_2)=4,d(v_3)=4$

Take $m=2$. then

$d(v_1)=m\times 3,d(v_2)=m\times 2,d(v_3)=m\times 2$

Now, you want to know if there is a sub-graph, with degrees

$d(v_1')=(m-1)\times 3=3,d(v_2)=(m-1)\times 2=2,d(v_3)=(m-1)\times 2=2$

Assume there exists such a sub-graph and there is a total of $t$ edges in the sub-graph. Then

$\sum d(v_i')=2\times t=7$

Which gives a contradiction, as $t$ is not a whole number.

Thinking the same way, if $m$ is an even number, then $m-1$ is odd. Therefore, you might wanna have

$\sum_{i\in V} d(x_i)=2k$

But it is a necessary condition.

Comment: Funny thing is I actually wanted the condition $\sum d(x_i)=$even in my calculation but somehow managed to slip up and forget.

Comment: Sometimes, you don't expect to see a solution, which  is "as simple as that".